# How to express the following probability expectation?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

A total of n bar magnets are bent slightly such that they can form a circle. 
There is 1/2 chance for each bar magnet to be in any orientation. 
Adjacent magents with opposit poles facing each other join to form a block.
What is the expected number of blocks?

My attempt:
Heuristical view
There are n number of possible links between n magnets in the circle.
If n link, 1 block. If n-1 link, 1 block. If n-2 link, 2 blocks
Hence, if i link broken, there are i blocks.

So E[no blocks]=sum from 1 to n[Indicator R.V that the ith link is broken]

But then I run into a problem. 0 broken links implies 1 block. How do i express that in my expectation function?

Comment: An interesting observation is that an odd number of broken links is impossible. However, this won't solve the problem you stated, since $0, 2, 4, 6, \dots$ broken links would result in $1, 2, 4, 6, \dots$ blocks.

Comment: Odd number of broken links should be possible, why not? 1 broken = 1 block, 3 broken = 3 blocks

Comment: Try to draw such a circle with 1 broken link and you quickly realize what's happening :). In each connected link, there are 1 north pole and 1 south pole. In each broken link, there are either 2 north poles or 2 south poles. With an odd number of broken links, the number of north and south poles cannot be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate it separately:
$$
E[\textrm{number of blocks}] = \sum_{k=1}^n P(k \textrm{ blocks}) k = P(1\textrm{ block}) + \sum_{k=2}^n P(k \textrm{ blocks}) k \\
= \dots = P(0\textrm{ broken links}) + \sum_{k=1}^n P(k \textrm{ broken links}) k \\
= P(0\textrm{ broken links}) + \sum_{k=0}^n P(k \textrm{ broken links}) k = \dots
$$

---

I just realized the solution can be written a bit more elegantly:

Let $X$ be the random variable describing the number of broken links and $Y$ be the random variable defined by
$$
Y = \begin{cases} 1,&\textrm{if no broken links}\\ 0,&\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}.
$$
Now the number of blocks is $X+Y$, so $E[X+Y]=\dots$